# How to start a devcontainer in vscode with bash instead of sh?

Tags: bash, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

All my devcontainers start always with sh, I have to manually type /bin/bash every time.

I first tried adding

```
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

at the end of my Dockerfile, but it still starts with ˋshˋ.

THen I tried doing this on my devcontainer:

```
{
    "name": "My environment",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "remoteUser": "dev",
    "settings": {
        "terminal.integrated.shell.linux": "/bin/bash"
      },
    "postCreateCommand": "/bin/bash"
}
```

but it still starts with sh and then keeps running the /bin/bash post create command forever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The settings can be overriden by SHELL variable.

Try to insert :

```
"containerEnv": {
    "SHELL": "/bin/bash"
}
```